# `\str_if_eq:NcTF` does not work but `\str_case:NnTF` does?

Tags: expl3

Why is the commented code (with `\str_case:NnTF`) working but the code with `\str_if_eq:NcTF` not?

I want to overwrite the value of `\l__ghs_signalword` only if is not set to `Gefahr`...

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\str_clear_new:N \l__ghs_signalword

\cs_new:Nn \ghs_setsignalword:n {
    
    %   \str_case:NnTF \l__ghs_signalword 
    %       {{ Gefahr } { }}
    %       { }
    %       { \str_gset:Nn \l__ghs_signalword { #1 } }
    
    \str_if_eq:NcTF \l__ghs_signalword { Gefahr } { }
    { \str_gset:Nn \l__ghs_signalword { #1 } }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\GHSgetsignalword}{}{
    \str_use:N \l__ghs_signalword
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\GHSsetsignalword}{m}{
    \ghs_setsignalword:n { #1 }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
    currently: \GHSgetsignalword \\
    \GHSsetsignalword{Achtung}
    currently: \GHSgetsignalword \\
    \GHSsetsignalword{Gefahr}   
    currently: \GHSgetsignalword \\
    \GHSsetsignalword{Achtung}
    currently: \GHSgetsignalword \\

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\str_if_eq:NcTF \l__ghs_signalword { Gefahr }
```

is comparing
`\l__ghs_signalword` and `\Gefahr`  but the latter is not defined so will act as `\relax`.  `c` means create a csname as the argument.

I think you want

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\str_clear_new:N \l__ghs_signalword

\cs_new:Nn \ghs_setsignalword:n {
    
    %   \str_case:NnTF \l__ghs_signalword 
    %       {{ Gefahr } { }}
    %       { }
    %       { \str_gset:Nn \l__ghs_signalword { #1 } }
    
    \str_if_eq:VnF \l__ghs_signalword { Gefahr } 
    { \str_gset:Nn \l__ghs_signalword { #1 } }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\GHSgetsignalword}{}{
    \str_use:N \l__ghs_signalword
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\GHSsetsignalword}{m}{
    \ghs_setsignalword:n { #1 }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    
    currently: \GHSgetsignalword \\
    \GHSsetsignalword{Achtung}
    currently: \GHSgetsignalword \\
    \GHSsetsignalword{Gefahr}   
    currently: \GHSgetsignalword \\
    \GHSsetsignalword{Achtung}
    currently: \GHSgetsignalword \\

\end{document}
```

Comment: And how can I get it to work with any `\str_if_eq`?

Comment: @mrCarnivore added example

Comment: Thank you. That works and was what I was looking for. How could I have found `\str_if_eq:VnF`? It is not in the `interface` document...

Comment: @mrCarnivore yes it is (underlined FT means all of {} F T and FT versions are available)

Comment: I simple search was too simple I now realize. I need to get more used to the different letters in the commands after `:` and what exactly they do. Thanks!